# Trouble Calculating for $30 \cos(30x)+14=−16$

Tags: trigonometry

I am unable to see how,

$$30\cos(30x)+14=−16$$

is equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{30} + n \frac{\pi}{15}$$

I solved up to this

$$\cos(30x) = -1$$
$$\pi= 30x$$
$$\frac{\pi}{30} = x$$

But I am unsure where the $\frac{\pi}{15}$ came from. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Note that $180=30x$ is not correct.  We are working in radians and you have ignored the periodicity of the cosine.

Comment: I will fix that right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't mix degrees and radians in the same solution without being explicit in what you're working with. It's bad practice, and simply incorrect if you're not very clear about what unit you're specifying.

So let's work only in radian measure.

$\displaystyle \cos(30x) = -1$

The reference angle with a cosine of $\displaystyle -1$ is $\displaystyle \pi$ radians. So $\displaystyle 30x = \pi$ is one solution.

However, there are an infinite number of solutions because of the periodicity of the cosine function, which has a period of $\displaystyle 2\pi$. So integer multiples of $\displaystyle 2\pi$ added to the reference angle will yield the same cosine.

So the full solution can be constructed as:

$\displaystyle 30x = \pi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{30} + \frac{n\pi}{15}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

as required.

This is equivalent to the *degree* solution: $\displaystyle x = (6 + 12n)^{\circ}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for giving a thorough explanation and for correcting me in my work.

Comment: @Compilerv2 Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you are at $$\cos(30x)=-1$$ your $180$ (which is degrees) is $\pi$ radians.  As the cosine function is periodic with period $2\pi$ we get 
$$30x=\pi+2k\pi$$
for any integer $k$.  Dividing by $30$ gives
$$x=\frac \pi{30}+\frac {k\pi}{15}$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute in $\pi/30$ and you get

$$\cos(30 \cdot \pi/30) = \cos \pi = -1.$$

Now repeat with some of your favorite integers $n$ and you'll see how it works. There is an infinite number of solutions to the equation: $\cos \pi, \cos 3\pi, \cos 5\pi, ... \cos -\pi, \cos -3\pi, ...$ all equal $-1$.

Comment: Yes, indeed there is an infinite number of solutions. The final answer I am looking for is a general statement for the infinite number of solutions. For example, I have one solution which says cos3pi and every time I add 2pi, I get to the same place in the unit circle, meaning I get another correct solution. I want my answer to be in general terms, articulating the infinite number of solutions in one formula.

Comment: Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is $\cos (x + 2n\pi ) = \cos x$ so if $\cos 30x = -1$ then $\cos 30(x+ \frac {2n\pi}{30})$ will *also* be equal to $-1$.

So when you got $\cos (30x ) = -1$ then

$30x = \pi$ is *ONE* of the possible values for $30x$ (because $\cos \pi = -1$).

$30x = 3\pi$ is another one (because $\cos 3\pi = -1)$ and $30x = -pi$ and $30x=5\pi$ and $30x = 2147\pi$ are some more (because $\cos -\pi = \cos 5\pi = \cos 2147 \pi = -1$).

Indeed for *any* integer, $n$, you have an infinite number of possibilities of $30x = (2n+1)\pi$ becase $\cos (2n+1)\pi = -1$.

So $x =\frac {\pi}{30}$ is one answer and $\frac {\pi}{10}$ or $-\frac {\pi}{30}$ and $\frac {\pi}{6}$ and $\frac {2147\pi}{30}$ are all also solutions because for *all* thus values of $x$ you'd have $30x = \{\pi,3\pi, -pi,5\pi, 2147\pi\}$ and $\cos 30x = -1$ for all of those.

In fact, there are an *infinite* number of solutions.  For any $\frac{\pi}{30} + \frac n{15}\pi$ you will have $\cos 30x = \cos (30(\frac {\pi}{30} + \frac n{15}\pi))=\cos (\pi + 2n \pi) = \cos \pi = -1$.

So those are an *infinite* number of solutions where $\cos 30x = -1$